Run antenna coax through hatchback of a Nissan Rogue
I have a 2014 Nissan Rogue and am trying to figure out best place to run my coax from a mag-mount antenna. Seems not many do this anymore and cannot find answer in search. Do not want to run it through windows, but not sure how to run it past liftgate without damaging cable... anyone know of a way without drilling holes in my car? Thanks!!

I have a Subaru Crosstrek, and my solution was some RG-176 cable.  It's small enough that I can just close the hatch over it, and since it's a short run, the loss isn't an issue.  And in your application, at 27MHz and in a car, the loss is not a problem.

There are a variety of "glass mount" antennas as well - parts are glued on the inside and outside of a window and the signal is inductively coupled through the glass. Can't have defroster wires.

Welcome to the site! I've edited your question a bit for clarity and to keep it on topic for this community... while this is not a CB focused site, the question you have about ways to run coax from a mag-mount antenna to your rig ARE relevant here as well.

While questions about CB are a bit out of scope, the frequency range and output power of the radio are relevant.

While I did consider a glass mount for my Tacoma, to get the antenna mounted on the bed rail, I ended up going for a mount on the hood and took the antenna cable through one of the firewall openings (with power coming in from an aux battery the other way). But I also found some rubber plugs on the floor in the back seat, and considered using a bulkhead connector there. Lots of options.

Usually there's enough "give" in the weatherstripping of a hatchback to pass coax of up to .200" diameter (the size of RG-58) without damaging the car (the coax does tend to get a bit "dented" over time but it will survive years of abuse without actually failing, in my experience).
But if you want to play it safer, simply use thinner coax, like RG-174, which is .100" diameter. A lot of mounts already come with skinny coax for that reason, and some other mounts can easily be disassembled and have new coax soldered or screwed to them.
At UHF frequencies, it may make sense to use just enough skinny coax to get inside the car, and then add a connector and transition to some thicker, lower-loss coax. But at 27MHz, RG-174 only loses 4-5 dB per 100 feet, which means the loss should be negligible for any run under 20 feet.
